# How to sort SQL results out of order?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

MSAccess 2007 SQL

I am writing a user search dropdown for values in a table column.

If the user types 'xyz' into the field, I want to find all rows where the search column starts-with or contains 'xyz'. But I want those rows where the column starts with 'xyz' to sort first, followed by those rows where that column contains 'xyz'. I know how to use a LIKE clause with wildcards to find the required rows, the question is on how to get the result set returned in the order below.

For example, if my search column contains:

- abcxyz
- mno
- xyzabc
- xyzmon
- 2xyz
- abcxyzruf
- zxyz

I want the query to return all rows where column contains 'xyz' in this order:

- xyzabc
- xyzmon
- 2xyz
- abcxyz
- abcxyzruf
- zxyz

What is the best, most efficient, only - way to make this happen with SQL in MSaccess 2007?

Comment: what is the logic for the sort?

Comment: David - those that start-with the search string come first sorted alphabetically ASC, and those that contain the search string come after those that start-with, and these will be sorted alphabetically ASC also.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `instr()`:

```
order by instr(col, "xyz")
```

Note:  This assumes that all strings have `"xyz"` in them.  If not, the non-matches will (unintuitively) come first.  However, for your sample data, all the values do have `"xyz"`.

EDIT:

For your revised version:

```
order by iif(col like "xyz*", 1, 2), col
```

Comment: Thx Gordon. Yes, all records will have 'xyz' in them. However, brilliant idea, but those that don't start-with 'xyz' will now be sorted based on where 'xyz' is found inside, instead of alphabetically. This means that 'zxyz' will come before 'aaaxyz'. I need those containing results to sort alphabetically after the rows that start-with 'xyz'.

Answer (score 0):

Gordon's answer got me on the right track.

```
Order By iif(instr(col, 'xyz')=1, instr(col, 'xyz'), col), col
```

That does it!!! Thanks so much Gordon.
The second col for Order By forces the starting-with sub-group to also sort alphabetically.